# Excel broke existing data import, how revert to before?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For years I had a semi-automated system for generating BOMs (bills of materials) for electrical designs.  Via a script in my CAD program, which runs some external code I wrote long ago, I get a tab-separated values (TSV) file.  This process also copies a template XLS file.  This file defines formatting for specific columns, which the TSV file can't contain.

I would open the template XLS file in Excel, then do something like DATA, FROM TEXT FILE, give it the file name, and hit return 5 times to take a bunch of defaults.  The data from the TSV file would appear in the spreadsheet, with the formatting from the template file.  Some cells contained equations instead of direct data.  This would all work as intended.

This procedure worked great for something like the last 15 years, until now.  Apparently Microsoft updated Excel on my Win10 laptop in the last few weeks, and everything is now broken.  What you get from *DATA > FROM TEXT > filename* is completely different.  All the controls from before are now missing, and now it guesses wrong.  I can find no obvious way to enable some "legacy" mode, nor do I see a way to give it more details.  It just does what it does, which is different from before, and it breaks my process.

It seems there are two incompatibilities that are really messing things up:

When the first cell in the first row contains a number, it now automatically adds its own title row.  I was using cell A1 as the total number of boards to build, so various quantities were computed from that number.  The remaining cells in the first row are my column titles.  I'm OK with the first column having a number at top.  That should be my business.

With it adding its own title row, all my equations are off by one vertically.  What at mess!

Equation import is broken.  When it gets a cell that contains "=" as the first character, it adds a space in front of the "=", then treats the rest as a string as a result.  If I manually edit out the space in the spreadsheet, then I get the intended equation.  There are hundreds of such cells, so manually fixing them all is not an option.

**How do I get back to the previous operation?**  I'm no Excel whiz, and really don't want to be.  I want to get on with generating my BOMs.

As an experiment, I manually converted a few lines of the TSV file to a CSV file.  Importing that results in the same problems.  Just typing the CSV file name brings up Excel with the data loaded correctly, but of course it doesn't know about my column formatting that way.

It shouldn't be hard to find the program that generates the TSV file under a large layer of dust someplace, and make changes as necessary.  For example, if I absolutely need a CSV file now, I can live with that.  I think I created a TSV file long ago to get around special characters in text strings in some of the cells.  Again, this all worked for years until a few weeks ago.

Comment: Hello Olin, have a look at this link: https://kb.parkland.edu/page.php?id=81661 . I just had a play importing a basic TSV file into excel and as you say it appears impossible to just get it to put the values in the damn cells rather than autoformatting the hell out of it. I recommend importing into a blank sheet, using table design to remove all formatting, then copy and paste the values into the template. If this works then you could link a macro to do the same. If you need to trim the values to get rid of spaces this can be built into the copy-paste-trim macro. I can help if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you select and open a file to import, it opens a new workbook and pastes only the values, I modified slightly from [here](https://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/automatic-import-textfile.htm) .

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim fullpath As String

' Makro1 Makro
' Makro indspillet 13-07-2013 af Eric Bentzen
'

'
'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.TSV; *.TXT; *.CSV , 1"
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show
        
        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        
    End With
    
On Error GoTo EndSub

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fullpath, _
   Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
   TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
   Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
   Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
   Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
   Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), _
   Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1)), _
   TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   
EndSub:

End Sub
```

It looks like it might only do 13 lines, but could be modified to suit.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to digest this a bit.  I was hoping there was a simple "legacy" setting or something.  I know nothing about the Excel macro language, so I'm a bit uncomfortable using a script that I can't maintain into the future.  Where is all this documented?

Comment: Alt F11 to open the window, then insert a macro and run by placing the cursor in the code and pressing the green run button. You can attach to a button later on. Don't worry, no virus.

Comment: sorry, the above should say "insert a module" not a macro. The code worked quite quickly on my system, did you have any luck? What do you mean by documented? Each of the commands used in the macro is covered in the microsoft office dev centre, for example application.filedialog is here:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog

Comment: However, getting help and examples of use of the commands is usually easier in the forums, I generally use this one, Ozgrid and excelforum - but usually a google search such as "vba application.filedialog" or "vba return filename and path selected file" will quickly return more useful information than the microsoft documentation (unless I guess you really need a deep understanding of the code, which I do not... so long as it works and works fast I am generally happy). Error catching can be good, and you could include an err.clear line in the code above to remove any error.